# A problem regarding superfluous constructions

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, adjectives, pronouns

There is a sentence that I found in an editorial.

> Victory in Baghouz will also mean the IS’s **territorial caliphate** is shattered.

According to cambridge dictionary meaning of **caliphate** is

> **an Islamic state, especially one ruled by a single religious and political leader**.

My question is when caliphate itself means an state or area why is it qualified by adjective territorial?

Thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 4):

**Caliphate** can refer to:

- the form of the organization of the state (as opposed to republic, empire...);
- the area of land occupied by that state.

The adjective **territorial** is used in order to remove the uncertainty and make it clear that the statement refers to the area of land.

From [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caliphate):

> caliphate (n.) = the **office** of a caliph or the **land** he rules over